Powershell not returning files with a CreationTime "less than" specified DateTime
In PowerShell 5.1, I'm trying to list all files on a given date with a CreationTime between two datetime values:
$fileDate = Get-Date -Date "2024-12-24 00:00:00"            #sets the date in question
$path = "D:\Temp\$(Get-Date $fileDate -Format "yyyyMMdd")"  #set the path
$fileLowerTime = $fileDate.addHours(12)                     #lower time boundary 12PM
$fileUpperTime = $fileDate.addHours(14)                     #upper time boundary 2PM

Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -ge $fileLowerTime) -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $fileUpperTime)}

When I run the above I get no results.
If I remove the $fileUpperTime comparison...
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -ge $fileLowerTime}
...I get a list of all files created on or after 12PM, as expected.
However, if I remove the $fileLowerTime comparison...
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $fileUpperTime}
...I again get no results.
Since the "less than" result set should include everything in the "greater than or equal to" result set, the flaw is obviously somewhere in the "less than" comparison.
Note: If I use LastWriteTime instead of CreationTime it works as expected, but I still want to know why using CreationTime doesn't work.
